# Batch converting csv files to xls on a Mac

Tags: microsoft-excel, conversion, csv

I would like to convert all the csv files in a directory to xls files. Nick T  posted this code here [How to batch convert .csv to .xls/xlsx](https://superuser.com/questions/301431/how-to-batch-convert-csv-to-xls-xlsx)

```
import os
import glob
import csv
import xlwt # from http://www.python-excel.org/

for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):
    wb = xlwt.Workbook()
    ws = wb.add_sheet('data')
    with open(csvfile, 'rU') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for r, row in enumerate(reader):
            for c, val in enumerate(row):
                ws.write(r, c, val)
    wb.save(csvfile + '.xls')
```

However when I run this I get an error coming from the last line.

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xef in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Anyone know how I can get rid of this? I am working in Terminal on a Mac.

Comment: Any non-ASCII characters in filenames? And which version of Python? V2 or V3?

Comment: No filenames are all just letters and numbers. Python V2

Comment: Then it's your data that contains non-ASCII characters.. By  default xwlt only assumes ASCII, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184454/has-anyone-been-able-to-write-out-utf-8-characters-using-pythons-xlwt) for a solution (if you are lucky the second one could be enough).

Answer (score 0):

I updated this code so it will work on python 3.5 by getting two lines out of the loop (`wb = xlwt.Workbook()` and `wb.save('output.xls')` were inside the loop).

```
 import os
 import glob
 import csv
 import xlwt
 wb = xlwt.Workbook() # put the xlwt out of the loop 
 for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):
         fpath = csvfile.split("/", 1)
         fname = fpath[1].split(".", 1)
         ws = wb.add_sheet(fname[0])
         with open(csvfile, 'r') as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f)
            for r, row in enumerate(reader):
                for c, col in enumerate(row):
                    ws.write(r, c, col)

 #Save the results once the loop is done
 wb.save('output.xls')
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User, and thanks for helping with this question.  Any chance you could add a couple of sentences to explain what you changed and why (for context)?

Comment: I do not know why "wb = xlwt.Workbook()" and wb.save('output.xls') were inside the loop.